# How to stop notifications on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, notification

I now have Ubuntu 18.04 running as a server on a spare Dell Inspiron 14R laptop (long story, don't ask :p)  Just the command line, not the desktop.

With varying frequency, I'm getting alerts on the monitor about **over-current conditions** with the usb ports.
This "might" be related to usb power surge alerts I got when the laptop had Windows, which somehow I was able to turn off and the laptop functioned with no issues.

I think it was a port tied to the touchscreen. Whether these are ignorable errors with Linux running, I'll investigate that separately.

For now, I'd like to turn the alerts off because they will display while I'm in the middle of editing or viewing a file.  Real annoying.

I haven't been able to find a topic related to turning notifications or alerts.

Edit 1: nothing connected to the usb ports. The alerts I'm getting off and on are "usb usb3-port3: over-current condition"   Sometimes it will say usb3-port4.  I've avoided the annoyance for now by ssh'ing to the laptop from another laptop

Comment: Please edit your question and include specific details. It's not clear what "alerts" you are talking about.

Comment: "over-current conditions", Hmm... is there anything connected to the related USB port(s)?

Comment: @Nmath, Hannu  See April 18 edits.  My workaround of ssh'ing to the laptop worked until I had to a restart.  Now I can't get the wifi connection to work so I cannot connect to the laptop.  I'm trying to resolve the wifi issue but the stupid "over-current" conditions alerts keep popping up and make it difficult to view the files I'm working on.   Need to turn these off, either by turning off alerts at the command line, or resolving the usb over-current situation.  I'm sure this is related to the usb port that the touch screen is connected (touchscreen not needed) Any idea how to disable alerts?

Comment: If you got similar warnings in Windows and nothing is plugged into these ports then you probably have a hardware problem. "over current" and "power surge" are similar enough to make this conclusion and it doesn't sound like something you should ignore. If you reinstall the OS and it still occurs then take the laptop in for service or the problem could spread to another component.